# QtCreator 2.7.0 & class browser

Tags: c++, class, ide, qt-creator

Does QtCreator 2.7.0 offers some kind of class browser that given some headers can help you to filter classes, members and so on ?

something like the html output from doxygen and its simple search engine.

I also found that suggestions for ctors are often incompletes or wrong, for example if a type offers more than 1 ctor only 1 is the suggested one.

For example I can build an `std::string` containing 10 **#** like so `std::string(10, '#')` but QtCreator doesn't say nothing about this.

There is something more complete as a class browser and ctor listing under Qtcreator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing that stopped you is just a bug, please report it to qt-project bugtracker or vote +1 to existing bug.

QtCreator have class browser in project tree (just switch mode on top of this widget from "Projects" to "Class View". It also can search for classes and for any C++ symbol (class, function, method, constructor, etc) with Quick Search.

Quick Search is an input filed on bottom panel (hotkey: Ctrk+K or Cmd+K on Mac OS X), which, by default, search by file names. If you enter "c ClassName", it will filter classes at whole project by substring "ClassName", and if you enter ": name", it will filter methods/classes/ctors/etc. at whole project by substring "name".

Comment: in the end qtcreator it's not offering that "something" I was looking for, kdevelop just offers a simple popup with a list of ctors signatures right when you are typing, qtcreator it's more cumbersome and less snappy.